# Unable to save recorded video in Google Glass XE 19.1

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to record a video from within my application using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

This opens the Video Recording mode. I record the video and then tap to accept the recording. However, the recorded video is never saved to the SD Card. I have written my code to write to the SD Card as follows.

```
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

    // Check that the SDCard is mounted
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "/Videos/MyCameraVideo");


    // Create the storage directory(MyCameraVideo) if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){

            output.setText("Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");

            Toast.makeText(ActivityContext, "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("App", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
            return null;
        }
    }


    // Create a media file name

    // For unique file name appending current timeStamp with file name
    java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                         .format(date.getTime());

    File mediaFile;

    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

        // For unique video file name appending current timeStamp with file name
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");

    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // After camera screen this code will excuted

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_VIDEO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //data is null over here
            status.setText("Video File : " +data.getData());

            Toast.makeText(this, "Video recorded successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } 

    }
}
```

Also, On debug, my data for the `onActivityResult` method is null.

Can please someone tell me how to write the video to the SD card. My above code works fine when tested on an Android phone but does not do the same in Glass. Is it a bug?

Comment: Are you trying to write video from google glass to SD card on your android device? Then may be you need to use bluetooth..

Comment: no @PrasannaAarthi. I am trying video into glass sd card only. not on Android device. Google glass has 16 GB SD card

Comment: SD card is different from flash memory I guess.

Answer (score 0):

onActivityResult will be null because the video is not done with processing.You need to use a File Observer and wait till the media is completely processed.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(
                CameraManager.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);
        processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
    final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

    if (pictureFile.exists()) {
        // The picture is ready; process it.
    } else {
        // The file does not exist yet. Before starting the file observer, you
        // can update your UI to let the user know that the application is
        // waiting for the picture (for example, by displaying the thumbnail
        // image and a progress indicator).

        final File parentDirectory = pictureFile.getParentFile();
        FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(parentDirectory.getPath(),
                FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE | FileObserver.MOVED_TO) {
            // Protect against additional pending events after CLOSE_WRITE
            // or MOVED_TO is handled.
            private boolean isFileWritten;

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                if (!isFileWritten) {
                    // For safety, make sure that the file that was created in
                    // the directory is actually the one that we're expecting.
                    File affectedFile = new File(parentDirectory, path);
                    isFileWritten = affectedFile.equals(pictureFile);

                    if (isFileWritten) {
                        stopWatching();

                        // Now that the file is ready, recursively call
                        // processPictureWhenReady again (on the UI thread).
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }
}
```

This code is for saving a photo.It should be similar for videos.
I have taken this from GDK's official documentation.

Comment: this isn't working since glass was updated to XE 18.3 https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=308